# Django admin page not found, following tutorial

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I've checked the other answers to this question but none solve my problem.

I'm using python anywhere and following the tutorial. I'm using Djano 1.8 through a virtual server. I'm getting stuck on Part 2 of the tutorial, right after you create the admin page. I create an admin user but nothing happens to the admin page. I get "Page not found."

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    #YOUR URLS GO HERE

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I'm not sure what else to show here. I've literally been following the tutorial so I don't understand what could be going wrong here. Yes, I'm reloading my web app. Still nothing.

Comment: Is the 'admin' app enabled in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
# Admin
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'apps.area.context_processors.socials',
)
```

Comment: you can see the page : http://localhost:8000/ 'Welcome Django'?  please show the way you use? http://localhost:8000/admin?

Comment: Yes I could see the Welcome Django page but not the admin page. I was doing mysite.pythonanywhere.com/admin/

Answer (score 0):

I learned from the pythonanywhere support team that it was because I hadn't edited the wsgi file and uncommented the django code. This is now fixed in the wiki tutoril for pythonanywhere and django.